How to use all the functions of Chart.js in a php controller
I'm transferring the graphic generation from js code to php, but functions such as borderRadius and legend => display = false don't work. I need borderRadius, because roundedBars does not completely make the stacks round.And how do I change asixY, I need to change it to string in increments of 2.
Php:
$backgroundColor = [];
        $borderColor = [];

        foreach ($dataValues as $value) {
            if ($value == 2) {
                $backgroundColor[] = 'rgba(52, 208, 114, 1)';
                $borderColor[] = 'rgba(52, 208, 114, 1)';
            }
            elseif ($value == 6) {
                $backgroundColor[] = 'rgba(249, 69, 71, 1)';
                $borderColor[] = 'rgba(249, 69, 71, 1)';
            } else {
                $backgroundColor[] = 'rgba(252, 252, 252, 1)';
                $borderColor[] = 'rgba(252, 252, 252, 1)';
            }
        }
        $chartConfig = [
            'type' => 'bar',
            'data' => [
                'labels' => $labels,
                'datasets' => [[
                    'label' => ' ',
                    'data' => $dataValues,
                    'backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor,
                    'borderColor' => $borderColor,
                    'borderWidth' => 1,
                    'borderRadius' => 50,
                    'borderSkipped' => false
                ]]
            ],
            'options' => [
                'scales' => [
                    'x' => [
                        'grid' => ['display' => false],
                        'border' => ['display' => false]
                    ],
                    'y' => [
                        'grid' => ['display' => false],
                        'border' => ['display' => false],
                        'beginAtZero' => true,
                    ]
                ],
                'plugins' => [
                    "roundedBars" => true,
                    "legend" => [
                        'labels' => [
                            'fontColor' => 'transparent',
                            'usePointStyle' => true,
                            'pointStyleWidth' => 0,
                            'boxWidth' => 0,
                        ],
                        [
                            "display" => false
                        ]
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $quickChartUrl = 'https://quickchart.io/chart/create';

        $response = Http::post($quickChartUrl, [
            'chart' => json_encode($chartConfig),
            'width' => 500,
            'height' => 300,
            'format' => 'png',
            'backgroundColor' => 'transparent'
        ]);

        if ($response->successful()) {
            $chartUrl = $response->json('url');

            $imageContent = file_get_contents($chartUrl);

            $imageName = 'chart_' . time() . '.png';

            $imagePath = public_path('chart/' . $imageName);

            if (!file_exists(public_path('chart'))) {
                mkdir(public_path('chart'), 0777, true);
            }

            file_put_contents($imagePath, $imageContent);

            if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
                return 'chart/' . $imageName;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to save image in public/chart');
            }
        }

Here's what the graph looks like after the php code

quickchart.io seems to be using an older version of chart.js. In the Introduction they link to chart.js v2.9.4. The differences in the configuration from a modern version of chart.js are numerous, for example the axes should be defined under xAxes and yAxes each of which should contain an array of objects (so yAxes => [['beginAtZero'=>true, .....]]), legend is not under plugins but directly under options; borderRadius was simply not implemented, etc.
